# Variable getting lost after user input in while loop Python 3x

Tags: python-3.x

Ill start off by saying I'm very much a beginner in coding and I'm working with an online course to learn. Unfortunately I've come up against an issue which I cant seem to find a work around.

I'm trying to read a line from command.txt file and then assign it to a variable. (cl1 & cl2) I'm then asking for input from the user, and then (within a while loop) if that users input matches the variable to open up another file and follow the action. and if it doesn't to then ask the question again.

Here is my code currently:

```
user1 = open ("holiday.txt", "w")
user1.write ("Holiday Location: " + holiday_loc + "\n")
user1.write ("Total Price: £" + str(total_price) + "\n")
user1.write ("Total People: " + str(total_people) + "\n")
user1.close()
print ("Here are a list of commands")
commands = open ("commands.txt", "r")
# command_line 1 = show data
# command_line2 = price PP
command_line1 = commands.readline()
command_line2 = commands.readline()
print (command_line1 + command_line2)
commands.close()
cl1 = command_line1
cl2 = command_line2
answer = input ("What would you like to do? ")
while answer != "cl1" or answer != "cl2":
    print("Im sorry, there is no such command")
    answer = input("What would you like to do? ")
else:
    if answer == cl1:
        show_data = open ("holiday.txt", "r")
        line1 = show_data.readline()
        line2 = show_data.readline()
        line3 = show_data.readline()
        print (line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3)
    elif answer == cl2:
        print (line2/line3)
```

So Clarification:

What i would like is:

The user inputs "show data" or "price pp" then it should skip to:

```
else:
        if answer == cl1:
            show_data = open ("holiday.txt", "r")
            line1 = show_data.readline()
            line2 = show_data.readline()
            line3 = show_data.readline()
            print (line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3)
        elif answer == cl2:
            print (line2/line3)
```

Currently if user inputs "show data" or "price pp" it just runs the loops:

`What would you like to do? show data
Im sorry, there is no such command
What would you like to do?`

it seems to me that the variable assignment is getting lost along the way maybe? or its a mix up with strings. im not sure.

ive tried all variations of

`while answer != "cl1" or answer != "cl2":`
`while answer != cl1 or answer != cl2:`
`while answer != "cl1" and answer != "cl2":`
`while answer != cl1 and answer != cl2:`

the following: `while answer != cl1 and answer != cl2:` works if user input cl1 or cl2 but i want it to work if the user types the commands instead of the variable names.

I hope that explains my problem.

Comment: Quick clarifying question: What is the intended result of `line2/line3`? Those two values are strings and therefore cannot be divided.

Comment: This is will be another command, ATM it's just there as an example of more then one command

Answer (score 0):

The line `while answer != cl1 and answer != cl2:` (without " " on cl1 and cl2) should work unless your `commands.txt` file contains the strings "cl1" and "cl2". What does your `commands.txt` file contain?

Comment: Two strings "show data" and "price pp" which if I print cl1 and cl2 before asking for input from the user it shows it assigning then correct but then not getting picked up in the users question